# How can I add the matching elements of two lists in dart?

Tags: dart

I have two lists of integers in Dart that are the same length, and wish to return the first list with the *matching elements of the second list added* to each integer.

Currently I'm using `asMap` and `forEach` to update elements using their indexes:

```
  List listA = [1,2,3];
  List listB = [4,5,6];
  listA.asMap().forEach((index, value) {
    listA[index] = listA[index] + listB[index];
  });
  print(listA); \\ [5, 7, 9]
```

This works, but feels inelegant.

**Is there a better, more *dart-way* of doing this?**

(Performance is not an issue for me as the respective lists will only have a few elements each at most.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a normal `for` loop instead of contorting your code to use `.forEach`; it's simple, straightforward, and readable:

```dart
List listA = [1,2,3];
List listB = [4,5,6];

assert(listA.length == listB.length);
for (var i = 0; i < listA.length; i += 1) {
  listA[i] += listB[i];
}
print(listA); // [5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution zips together one or more lists, returning the list of sums.  You can paste this into dartpad to play with it.

```
void main() {
  var a = List.generate(10, (e) => e);
  var b = List.generate(15, (e) => e * 100);
  var c = List.generate(20, (e) => e * 10000);
  print(sumIt([a, b, c]));
}

Iterable sumIt(List<List<num>> lists) sync* {
  var its = lists.map((e) => e.iterator).toList();

  while (true) {
    var done = true;
    var sum = 0.0;
    for (var it in its) {
      if (it.moveNext()) {
        done = false;
        sum += it.current;
      }
    }
    if (done) break;
    yield sum;
  }
}
```

It's also a good exposure to creating an Iterable using yield.